# What kind of "Key" do I need to supply when loading Resource Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In trying to set a default `ResourceDictionary` I receive the following warning:

> The designer does not support loading dictionaries that mix
>   'ResourceDictionary' items without a key and other items in the same
>   collection. Please ensure that the 'Resources' property does not
>   contain 'ResourceDictionary' items without a key, or that the
>   'ResourceDictionary' item is the only element in the collection.

This is the code that I am using in my **App.xaml** file, that received the above warning:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Lang.en-US.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is the exact same code that I've used to set a `ResourceDictionary` in Visual Studio 2008. I am now using VS 2010. What `Key` do I need to provide this `ResourceDictionary` for it to work correctly?

This is the line in my **MainWindow.xaml** that I am currently testing along with this code:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource new_test}" />
```

Comment: You have more resource in application or is this it?

Comment: I have more than one. But this is also the case when I used this method in VS 2008 and it worked

Comment: Try giving `x:Key` to your root element `ResourceDictionary` just below `Application.Resources`.

Comment: Can you show them as well?

Comment: @RohitVats If I give `ResourceDictionary` `x:Key` what do I set it as? (`x:Key="?"`). And I can show the dictionaries if you need them.

Comment: Yeah please post them.

Comment: By more resource in application i mean in tag `Application.Resources`. Are you declaring some other resources apart from merged dictionary?

Comment: For translations you should use Resources and not ResourceDictionary

Comment: Not that I know of. I have things like `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`, `ContextMenu`, and `Style` in my `App.xaml`. Does that matter?

Comment: @devhedgehog In the past, I found `ResourceDictionaries` to work better. If `Resources` are a good way as well, maybe posting an answer with an implementation of it would help.

Comment: I gave you an example. Resource files are ment to be used for translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your complete XAML file, i suspect there are other resources apart from merged dictionary in your resources section.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx) -

> It is legal to define resources within a ResourceDictionary that is
>   specified as a merged dictionary, either as an alternative to
>   specifying Source, or in addition to whatever resources are included
>   from the specified source. However, this is not a common scenario; the
>   main scenario for merged dictionaries is to merge resources from
>   external file locations. If you want to specify resources within the
>   markup for a page, you should typically define these in the main
>   ResourceDictionary and not in the merged dictionaries.

Try moving other resources in separate resource dictionary and make sure all other resources have `x:Key` set on them -

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Lang.en-US.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
             <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
             <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Do I need to make each item under `Application.Resources` have it's own `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: No, apart from merged dictionaries, wrap all other resources under single ResourceDictionary like i wrap contextMenu and converter under single dictionary. Put all other resources under this dictionary only.

Comment: And keep `MergedDictionaries` wrapped by it's own `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: Yeah like i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Or simply put all other resources in parent `ResourceDictionary` just after Application.Resources. I suspect other resources are lying outside of ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use resource file for translations. Its better than resource dictionary.

Here is an example:

Set prefix like this for usage in xaml.

```
xmlns:const="clr-namespace:FileExplorer.Properties"
```

Resources are located in properties.

To use them in XAML you will need following:

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static const:Resources.Window_Title_String}"/>
```

If you have different languages then create for each language own resource file following naming convention.

For example:

```
Resources.resx (this will be default)
Resources.de-DE.resx (this is for german)
```

Now you just have to set current culture to german for your app to be on german and the proper resource file will be used automatically.

Like this in Main method:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```